# How can I determine my QNAP BIOS version without root account?

Tags: linux, qnap

I would like to determine the BIOS version of a QNAP NAS, using console (SSH) without using a root account.

That means I can't go through:

```
dmidecode -s bios-version
```

I have this solution for now:

```
dmesg | grep DMI | grep BIOS
```

…but it only works as long as the information is still in dmesg.

Is there another way to check it?

It's better if the solution works for several different models, as I need to check 12 different models.